# Obtener datos de firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

estoy probando a usar firebase en mi aplicación, y tengo lo siguiente:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, age,phone, height;
    Button btnSave;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Member member;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        age = findViewById(R.id.age);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        height = findViewById(R.id.height);
        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        member = new Member();
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, listarMiembros.class);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int agea = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
                Float hit = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
                Long ph = Long.parseLong(phone.getText().toString());

                member.setName(name.getText().toString());
                member.setAge(agea);
                member.setHt(hit);
                member.setPhone(ph);

                reff.push().setValue(member);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Member value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Member.class);

                Log.i("loge", "value is " + value.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("loge", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });



    }
}
```

La cuestión en que la información se inserta correctamente en la base de datos en firebase, pero no se como obtener un listado de toda la información que hay almacenada.
He probado a hacer lo siguiente:

```
public class listarMiembros extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference reff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_miembros);

        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Member post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Member.class);
                System.out.println(post);
                Log.i("loge", "-- " + post);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Pero cuanod hago sout, me da el siguiente error: `W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Lz8mf489_bK9MfxEzyq found on class dam.android.carlos.connectionfirebase.Member`

Y mi clase Member la tengo asi:

```
public class Member {
    public Member member;
    private String name;
    private Integer Age;
    private Long phone;
    private Float ht;

    public Member(){

    }

    public Member(String name, Integer age, Long phone, Float ht) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.ht = ht;
    }
    public Member(Member menber, String name, Integer age, Long phone, Float ht) {
        this.member = menber;
        this.name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.ht = ht;
    }
    public Member getMember(){
        return member;
    }

    public void setMember(Member member){
        this.member = member;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Float getHt() {
        return ht;
    }

    public void setHt(Float ht) {
        this.ht = ht;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", Age=" + Age +
                ", phone=" + phone +
                ", ht=" + ht +
                '}';
    }
}
```

He estado investigando por mi cuenta, ya he añadido el public Member member. y un Member en el construcor, asi como el getter y setter de member, pero no ha funcionado.
En el Log.i("loge") me sale solo una liena (como si fuera la linea que acabo de insertar), pero todos los campos a null, en cambio en la base de datos si que aparece correctamente.
Soy nuevo en firebase.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: El mensaje es claro: *`No setter/field for -Lz8mf489_bK9MfxEzyq`*  indica que en la referencia que has puesto se está encontrando un objeto que tiene una propiedad `-Lz8mf489_bK9MfxEzyq`. Revisa cómo tienes organizados los datos, porque al parecer se están creando claves autogeneradas que no corresponden con la estructura de datos que tienes en la clase `Member`

Comment: En tu calse ```Member``` el primer atributo que defines es de la clase ```Member```.  Pero creo que al guardar en firebase no te guardará ese atributo, o te dará error, ya que los objetos no se pueden guardar en firebase.  Mira la documentación de los tipos de datos que soporta firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types?hl=es

Comment: Es que en firebase, me añade el `-Lz8mf489_bK9MfxEzyq`, y cuando lo despliego, es cuando me salen los atributos correctamente, tal que asi: https://photos.app.goo.gl/SKmjkDE4KLSa3bqS8  @A. Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

En lugar de `reff.push().setValue(member);` he puesto `reff.child(member.getName()).setValue(member);` para que el ID no sea la cosa rara que pone firebase por defecto, por lo que ahora, no puede haber dos miembros con el mismo nombre, ya que si lo haces, lo único que consigues es modificar el que ya existe en la base de datos.

Para listar los datos lo que hago es lo siguiente:  `System.out.println("listarMiembros: " 
 + dataSnapshot.child("Member").getValue().toString());`

Ahora la base de datos se queda con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Imagen de la estructura de la base de datos]

Y en el `System.out.println();` se muestra la siguiente información:

```
I/System.out: listarMiembros: {carlos={phone=55555, name=carlos, ht=33, age=23}, juan carlos={phone=3223232, name=juan carlos, ht=34, age=32}, Juan Pedro={phone=4242422424, name=Juan Pedro, ht=222, age=21}, juan={phone=222, name=juan, ht=2332, age=21}}
```

Y el código queda de la siguiente manera:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, age,phone, height;
    Button btnSave;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Member member;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        age = findViewById(R.id.age);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        height = findViewById(R.id.height);
        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        member = new Member();
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, listarMiembros.class);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int agea = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
                Float hit = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
                Long ph = Long.parseLong(phone.getText().toString());

                member.setName(name.getText().toString());
                member.setAge(agea);
                member.setHt(hit);
                member.setPhone(ph);

                reff.child(member.getName()).setValue(member);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

La clase Member:

```
public class Member {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Long phone;
    private Float ht;

    public Member(){

    }

    public Member(String name, Integer age, Long phone, Float ht) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.ht = ht;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Float getHt() {
        return ht;
    }

    public void setHt(Float ht) {
        this.ht = ht;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", Age=" + age +
                ", phone=" + phone +
                ", ht=" + ht +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Y la clase listarMiembros:

```
public class listarMiembros extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference reff;
    ArrayList<Member> miembros;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_miembros);
        miembros = new ArrayList<>();

        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Member post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Member.class);
                System.out.println("listarMiembros: " + dataSnapshot.child("Member").getValue().toString());
                Log.i("loge", "-- " + post);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }
}
```